# Accessing a file through .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

i'm new to stack overflow, and to .htaccess too, so let's come to the point.

I have a file `lessons(.php)` in my root directory and i want it to appear like it doesn't exists there through **.htaccess**

So i'm using these directives to achieve one of my goal:

```
<Files lessons.php>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
</Files>
```

I only know that i'm denying access to that file in my directory, nothing more

And my second question is that i want this file to be able to access only for certain conditions, means when someone try to access that link

```
RewriteRule ^library/lessons/([a-z-]+) lessons?lesson=$1 [NC,L]
```

In other words

```
library/lessons/ba-blah-blah-whatever/
```

So how i can do this, accessing file just like an **if/else** condition, means if someone is on that link mentioned up there can access that file, i know that i can't use **if/else** in **.htaccess** but you know what i want to say

Comment: You can make a rewrite rule to that file that redirects to a 404 not found or a 403 forbidden. And then, follow with the rules you have and it work like you need. Don't need the deny code

Comment: Who is the guy that is downvoting and vote to close this question? I think is legitime question for a novice.

Comment: **Thanks!** Your comment really help me. You're a great guy.

Comment: You're welcome man! We are learning something new everyday,huh? :D

Comment: There is another gotcha ! I want to check that if there is **lesson** in end the of url. How can i achieve this by .htaccess file ? Any idea ?

Comment: You have this: `([a-z-]+)`  in your regexp. It captures the end of the string and it's mandatory at least one character, so always capture that. You can check in PHP if the lesson exists or not, but in htaccess you have all.

Comment: So how can i use this pattern like if nothing exists there. I think like this `[^([a-z-]+)]` Right ?

Comment: `([a-z-]+)` means one or unlimited characters or dashes. `([a-z-]*)` means zero or unlimited characters or dashes. `^` means start of the string. You can test all your regexp here: https://regex101.com/ This page explains you what are you writting in a regexp and allows you to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you don't need anything so complicate. Just write a proper route with mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^library/lessons/([a-z-]+) lessons.php?lesson=$1 [NC,L]
```

... and if you really really can't allow access through the actual file name, prevent access right from PHP filtering `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and aborting with 404 status code.

Comment: **Thanks** for your time.